# External Css stylesheet not linked to my HTML

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

My External css file is not linked to my html page.
I had with inside a folder with path

```
->app-->css-->layout.css
->index.html
```

In my index.html file I linked it like 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="app/css/layout.css">` 
it won't link it.
i searched for the file in the chrome (`inspect-->sources`) and the css file wasn't listed there

I then put the layout.css and index.html in the same path.
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="layout.css">`

it still didn't work. I checked in multiple browser like chrome and firefox as well but it didn't work.

Comment: where is you index.html file? In app folder ?

Comment: have you tried href="/app/css/layout.css" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the command below to get the desired result

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
```

Its a very common mistake that everyone do... Please notice that here type="text/css" not
type/css...

Regards,
Om Chaudhary

Comment: Yes. I didn't notice that at all. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is causing the error(most probably is), but type should be `text/css` instead of `type/css`.

Comment: Yes. I didn't notice that . Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `type/css` to `text/css` and there is no need to write full path name in href.